# rank of a block matrix with known rank information

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Let $$ X = \begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ C & D \end{bmatrix}$$ where the number of rows of $A$, $C$ and $D$ are larger than those of columns.

- If both $\begin{bmatrix} A \\ C \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} C & D \end{bmatrix}$ are of full column rank, is $X$ also of full column rank?
- Or, can we say that $X$ is of full column rank if $\begin{bmatrix} C & D \end{bmatrix}$ are of full column rank?

Comment: If you have some linearly independent vectors and you extend each of them by appending some arbitrary new coordinates, then your longer vectors are "even more" linearly independent.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you mean that if $\begin{bmatrix} C &D \end{bmatrix}$ is of full column rank, so is $X$?

Comment: Yes that was my intention.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?